# How do I select element in JS table?

Tags: javascript, arrays

1.Im trying to make a table trough JS but I'm stuck with a little problem, I'm trying to put in the place of ?,  ID  so it fills in the IDs for me i just write id, but i don't know how to mention it  in or get it to take it.

2.Ive tried putting it in " " and ' '.

```
   var Applications =

[
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UID8', Name: ' (BV)'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UDWD', Name: 'AWS'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UAD5', Name: 'AMS'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'U548', Name: 'COine'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UADW', Name: 'GAine'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UADA', Name: 'EP'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UAHD', Name: 'ES'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UHH5', Name: 'GTR'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UHHA', Name: 'SPA '},
];
var txt= "";
Applications.forEach(table);
function table(item, index, arrays) {

    txt =  txt + "<tr><td>?????</td></tr>";

}
document.getElementById("tbl").innerHTML = txt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `table()` from your `forEach()`, you pass through each object inside `Applications` on each iteration of the forEach. You can access the object inside the function using the parameter `item`. Since the id is a nested value, you would access it like `item.ID`:

```js
var Applications = [
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UID8', Name: ' (BV)'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UDWD', Name: 'AWS'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UAD5', Name: 'AMS'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'U548', Name: 'COine'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UADW', Name: 'GAine'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UADA', Name: 'EP'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UAHD', Name: 'ES'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UHH5', Name: 'GTR'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UHHA', Name: 'SPA '},
];

var txt = "";

Applications.forEach(table);

function table(item, index, arrays) {

  txt = txt + "<tr><td>" + item.ID + "</td></tr>";

}

document.getElementById("tbl").innerHTML = txt;
```

```html
<table id="tbl"></table>
```

You could simplify your code using `reduce`:

```js
var Applications = [
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UID8', Name: ' (BV)'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UDWD', Name: 'AWS'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UAD5', Name: 'AMS'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'U548', Name: 'COine'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UADW', Name: 'GAine'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UADA', Name: 'EP'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UAHD', Name: 'ES'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UHH5', Name: 'GTR'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UHHA', Name: 'SPA '},
];

var txt = Applications.reduce((acc, item) => acc + "<tr><td>" + item.ID + "</td></tr>", '');

document.getElementById("tbl").innerHTML = txt;
```

```html
<table id="tbl"></table>
```

Comment: The text is inserted between `tr` and `td`. You should parse the text inside the `td` instead.

Comment: @C0mpl3x No problem. If you need any more help, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can use template strings to insert a variable inside a string.
See below

[template literals( strings )](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
   var applications = [{
         cluster: 'WV',
         ID: 'UID8',
         Name: ' (BV)'
       },
       {
         cluster: 'WV',
         ID: 'UDWD',
         Name: 'AWS'
       },
       {
         cluster: 'WV',
         ID: 'UAD5',
         Name: 'AMS'
       },
       {
         cluster: 'WV',
         ID: 'U548',
         Name: 'COine'
       },
       {
         cluster: 'WV',
         ID: 'UADW',
         Name: 'GAine'
       },
       {
         cluster: 'WV',
         ID: 'UADA',
         Name: 'EP'
       },
       {
         cluster: 'WV',
         ID: 'UAHD',
         Name: 'ES'
       },
       {
         cluster: 'WV',
         ID: 'UHH5',
         Name: 'GTR'
       },
       {
         cluster: 'WV',
         ID: 'UHHA',
         Name: 'SPA '
       },
     ];
var tableHtml ='';
applications.forEach(function(item,index) {
  tableHtml = tableHtml + `<tr><td>${item.ID}</td></tr>`;
})

document.getElementById("tbl").innerHTML = tableHtml;
```

```html
<table id="tbl"></table>
```

Comment: Why are you using `applications[index].ID` when you could just use `item.ID`?

Comment: Because i had a lack of inspiration :) thanks for the comment. I just changed the solution a lot and left the wrong version.

Comment: No problem, easy mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can also generate the whole table like this,

```
<table border=1 id="tbl"></table>
<script>
   var Applications =

[
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UID8', Name: ' (BV)'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UDWD', Name: 'AWS'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UAD5', Name: 'AMS'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'U548', Name: 'COine'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UADW', Name: 'GAine'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UADA', Name: 'EP'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UAHD', Name: 'ES'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UHH5', Name: 'GTR'},
    {cluster: 'WV', ID: 'UHHA', Name: 'SPA '},
];
var txt= "";

txt=txt+"<tr>";
        Object.keys(Applications[0]).forEach((key)=>{
  txt =  txt + "<td>"+key+"</td>";
});
  txt=txt+"</tr>";
Applications.forEach(table);
function table(item, index, arrays) {
txt=txt+"<tr>";
        Object.keys(item).forEach((key)=>{
  txt =  txt + "<td>"+item[key]+"</td>";
});
  txt=txt+"</tr>";

}
document.getElementById("tbl").innerHTML = txt;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` method of `array` like below:

```js
var Applications =

  [{
      cluster: 'WV',
      ID: 'UID8',
      Name: ' (BV)'
    },
    {
      cluster: 'WV',
      ID: 'UDWD',
      Name: 'AWS'
    },
    {
      cluster: 'WV',
      ID: 'UAD5',
      Name: 'AMS'
    },
    {
      cluster: 'WV',
      ID: 'U548',
      Name: 'COine'
    },
    {
      cluster: 'WV',
      ID: 'UADW',
      Name: 'GAine'
    },
    {
      cluster: 'WV',
      ID: 'UADA',
      Name: 'EP'
    },
    {
      cluster: 'WV',
      ID: 'UAHD',
      Name: 'ES'
    },
    {
      cluster: 'WV',
      ID: 'UHH5',
      Name: 'GTR'
    },
    {
      cluster: 'WV',
      ID: 'UHHA',
      Name: 'SPA '
    },
  ];
  var txt= Applications.map(application=>`<tr><td>${application.ID}</td></tr>`).join('');
  console.log(txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution i guess for adding new columns after. Tanks for all the answers helped out a lot.

```
function generatetable(item, index, arrays) {
        var columns = "";

        columns = columns + "<td onclick='testfn(\"" + index + "\", this)'>" + item.UAID + "</td>";
        columns = columns + "<td>" + item.Name + "</td>";
        columns = columns + "<td>" + "<a href='https://echo.1dc.com/appmap/" + item.UAID + "/ApplicationDetails/'>Appmap</a>" + "</td>";

        txt = txt + "<tr>" + columns + "</tr>";
}
```